# no such file or directory, rename 'C:\username\my-proj-name\node_modules\.staging\readable-stream-d0b1a619'

Tags: node.js, express, npm-install, tedious

stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\username\my-proj-name\node_modules.staging\readable-stream-d0b1a619' -> 'C:\username\proj-name\my custom-module-name(tedious)\node_modules\bl\node_modules\readable-stream'

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed with below steps

1. delete **node-modules** folder
2. delete **package-lock.json**(or)**npm-shrinkwrap.json** which ever exist in your project.
3. do **npm install**

Answer (score 0):

run this command :

to upgrade npm

```
npm install -g npm 

npm cache clean
```

delete node_module file and

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

When i get similar errors ive had success buy killing/closing all running instances of node (I use process explorer on windows for this). Often its webstorm or vs code that has a node process open. After closing these programs and ensuring there is no running node process npm install works again.